# Find element in list n times Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

Given are

```
a = [1, 4, 2, 5]

b = [[[0, 1]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 3]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 6]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 3]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 4]],
     [[0, 5]], [[0, 6]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 1]],
     [[0, 5]], [[0, 1]], [[0, 1]]]
```

My goal is to iterate over the list `a` and to identify (`print`) those elements in `b` which have the element of `a` as element at `index 1`. The whole thing becomes difficult by the fact that this process may occur exactly three times for each element. After that, the next index in `a` is to be selected.
In concrete terms, the whole thing should look like this at the end:

```
[[0, 1]]
[[0, 1]]
[[0, 1]]
[[0, 4]]
[[0, 4]]
[[0, 4]]
[[0, 2]]
[[0, 2]]
[[0, 2]]
[[0, 5]]
[[0, 5]]
[[0, 5]]
```

All elements in `b` beyond that are to be ignored, even and especially if they occur more than three times.

I have already tried various techniques ( random, while loop, etc.), racked my brain and searched this forum, but I am stuck.

It doesn't matter which elements are selected in `b`, the main thing is that there are three for each element in `a`.

Comment: What should happen for elements with more than three repeats (like `[[0,1]]`) ? Or fewer ? And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Could exits elements in b like: b = [[[0, 1], [0, 5]], [[0, 2]], ...]?

Comment: I don't know what is so heavy to understand in my question. I wrote everything down.

Comment: You have however not provided any code. StackOverflow is a [questions and answers
site](https://stackoverflow.com/about), not a code-writing service. Please read
through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your
question to reflect your work.

Comment: @ljmc I also realize that stackoverflow is not a code writing service. I had simply hoped to convey a concept, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it easier, you can simply follow the steps below:

```py
a = [1, 4, 2, 5]

b = [[[0, 1]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 3]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 6]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 3]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 4]],
     [[0, 5]], [[0, 6]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 1]],
     [[0, 5]], [[0, 1]], [[0, 1]]]

for val_a in a:
    counter = 0
    for val_b in b:
       if val_a == val_b[0][1]:
           counter += 1
           if counter < 4:
                print(val_b)
```

I hope I could help! :D

Answer (score 1):

This will count and filter your `b` input on `a` values using a `Counter` to count the values and appending to the filtered list only is the value count is less than 3.

```py
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 4, 2, 5]

b = [
    [[0, 1]],
    [[0, 2]],
    [[0, 3]],
    [[0, 4]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 6]],
    [[0, 2]],
    [[0, 3]],
    [[0, 4]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 4]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 6]],
    [[0, 4]],
    [[0, 2]],
    [[0, 2]],
    [[0, 4]],
    [[0, 4]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 1]],
    [[0, 5]],
    [[0, 1]],
    [[0, 1]],
]

c = Counter()

b_filtered = []

b.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][-1])

for x in b:
    v = x[0][-1]
    if v in a and c[v] < 3:
        b_filtered.append(x)
    c[v] += 1
```

`b_filtered` contains

```py
[[[0, 1]],
 [[0, 1]],
 [[0, 1]],
 [[0, 2]],
 [[0, 2]],
 [[0, 2]],
 [[0, 4]],
 [[0, 4]],
 [[0, 4]],
 [[0, 5]],
 [[0, 5]],
 [[0, 5]]]
```

Comment: The code does what I asked for, however I am not experienced enough to understand everything yet. I have not yet dealt with lambda enough. Thanks anyway and no hard feelings.

Comment: No hard feelings, and this lambda simply tells `sort` how to access the value on which it should sort `b` so that you only need to count values out later.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps to achieve your desired output

```
a = [1, 4, 2, 5]
b = [[[0, 1]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 3]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 6]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 3]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 4]],
     [[0, 5]], [[0, 6]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 2]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 4]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 5]], [[0, 1]],
     [[0, 5]], [[0, 1]], [[0, 1]]]

result = []
count = {}
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if j[0][1] == i:
            if i not in count:
                count[i] = 1
                result.append(j)
            elif count[i] < 3:
                count[i] += 1
                result.append(j)

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Comment: if j[0][1] == I: gives me an error. Not subscriptable.